# Just display rows with 3 or more equal data in a column

Tags: sql

How can I display rows with 3 or more equal data in a column for example:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
```

so that my select on displays

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT YourColumn
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourColumn
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks, but my code does not work:SELECT Employee.Lastname, Employee.Firstnme, EMP_ACT.Projno FROM Employee Join EMP_ACT On Employee.Empno = EMP_Act.Empno GROUP BY EMP_Act.Projno HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3}

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!